# Why image size gets doubled when image get stored in document directory then Refetching doubles it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I fetch the Image from the server and store it in Document directory. During that time, image size shown is 127KB . But when I rerun the code, Image size I get is around 330 KB without any reason.

For retuning the image size, I use this code.

```
    NSData *imageData ;

    double imageresolution = 1.0;

    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, imageresolution);//(thumbnail, 1.0f);

    unsigned long len1 = 0;
    len1=[imageData length];
    NSLog(@"FinalImage File length......1: %lu",len1);
```

Comment: Possibly because at the start, it's wasn't in "High" quality? It's like taking a photo, downgrade its quality (adding "noise/blur", and save it that version in high quality.

Comment: It's in HIgh quality stored  at 1064*708. But how could possibly can t doubles the size. I don['t think this noise/blur can affect it.

Comment: may be you append the image data to existing file instead of rewrite it?

Comment: @heximal, I didn't append it.

Comment: if it is returned form a server is probably sent as a data object, when and how are you creating the `image` instance?

Comment: @Andrea, I'm fetching and saving in document directory and set in UIbutton. Im fetching the image from it by using uibutton.imageview.image.

Comment: Do the test:`UIImage *originalImage =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];[_img1 setImage:originalImage];NSLog(@"OriginalImageData: %@", @([imageData length]));NSData *midData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 0.5);UIImage *midImage = [UIImage imageWithData:midData];[_img2 setImage:midImage];NSLog(@"MidImageData: %@", @([midData length]));NSData *thirdData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(midImage, 1);UIImage *thirdImage = [UIImage imageWithData:thirdData];[_img3 setImage:thirdImage]; NSLog(@"ThirdImageData: %@", @([thirdData length]));
`

Comment: @Larme, It just reduces the the size from 325094 Bytes to 299903 Bytes but the actual size is 127000 Bytes. Why the actual size is not passing/returning?

Comment: @Larme, And when I return the directly NSData without storing in UIImage, It's returning original size. Why this happens?